# Excel VBA: Nested Loop does not concatenate values

Tags: excel, vba, nested-loops

The Sender (Consignor) and Receiver (Consignee) addresses are spread out in 3 different columns each. Hence I create 1 Consignor Address Column and 1 Consignee Address Column into which I want to concatenate the data.
Then I write 2 loops to go through and concatenate the values from the 3 cells.
The first loop works perfectly, while the second one does not really add the values, though when tested with F8 it does run the code so to say.
Can someone explain to me why that is?

```
Sub CnorCneeAddress()

Columns("Q:Q").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("Q1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Consignee Address"

Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Consignor Address"


Dim Worksheet As Worksheet
Set Worksheet = ActiveSheet
LastRow = Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


With Worksheet
For i = 2 To LastRow 'Starting from Row 2 until the LastRow (i , will change depending on the data in column j)
    For j = 10 To 12
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value
        ElseIf j = 12 Then
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value & Cells(i, j).Value
        Else
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value & Cells(i, j).Value & ", "
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End With

With Worksheet
For i = 2 To LastRow 'Starting from Row 2 until the LastRow (i , will change depending on the data in column j)
    For j = 14 To 16
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 17).Value = Cells(i, 17).Value
        ElseIf j = 16 Then
        Cells(i, 17).Value = Cells(i, 17).Value & Cells(i, j).Value
        Else
        Cells(i, 17).Value = Cells(i, 17).Value & Cells(i, j).Value & ", "
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Columns("M:O").Delete
Columns("J:L").Delete

End With



End Sub
```

While the data for the Consignor is concatenated correctly, the cells under Consignor Address remain empty.

I do not understand why my code does not concatenate the cells for the Consignee Address.

Comment: It is very hard to know why from your example, as it is not reproducible. We have no example data to reuse, and the address usage `"Consignee Address"` could be both a saved variable or just a string. A few pointers is available though. First of all, your `with ... end with` statements has no effect currently. Add a `.` in front of `cells(i, ...)` to force it to use cells from the worksheet specified. Like `with Worksheet: .cells(i, 9) = ...` would force it to manipulate the cell in `worksheet`. I am betting that this is a reference issue, and you are simply refering to the wrong cells.

Comment: If there is an anlogy between first and the second part,I would change  "For j = 14 To 16" -> "For j = 15 To 17" and "ElseIf j = 16 Then" to "ElseIf j = 17 Then". But the logic in your code seems strange to me.

Comment: Not a solution, but I'd recommend using a variable name that isn't also the data type and offers some description of the contents. For example AddressSheet rather than Worksheet.

Comment: im more confused as to why we're doing two different loops when the first loop should handle all fo the logic. Then there's the whoile looping through the cells in the sheet itself.

Comment: When you inserted a new `Column I`,  you shifted the other columns to the right, so `Column Q` became `Column R` and rows 14, 15, and 16 are now 15, 16, and 17.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your comments. Let me try to make things clearer.

I have data looking roughly so, after the column insertion, that is considered:

Columns 10, 11, 12 are "Consignor City", "Consignor State", "Consignor Post Code"
Column 14, 15, 16 are "Consignee City", Consignee State", "Consignee Post Code"
All variables are strings or integers e.g. if postcode in US..

Please see below picture.

Currently I have the code below running somewhat. I am working with VBA since 4 days, I have taken advanced Python before, so forgive me for still not understanding exactly how VBA works.

[How the columns look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2mZH.png)

```
Sub CnorCneeAddress()

 Columns("N:N").Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
 Range("N1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Consignee Address"

 Columns("I:I").Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
 Range("I1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Consignor Address"


 Dim Worksheet As Worksheet
 Set Worksheet = ActiveSheet
 lastRow = Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row


 With Worksheet
 For i = 2 To lastRow 'Starting from Row 2 until the LastRow (i , will change depending on the data in column j)
    For j = 10 To 12
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value
        ElseIf j = 12 Then
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value & Cells(i, j).Value
        Else
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value & Cells(i, j).Value & ", "
        End If
    Next j
 Next i
 End With

 With Worksheet
 For i = 2 To lastRow 'Starting from Row 2 until the LastRow (i , will change depending on the data in column j)
    For j = 15 To 17
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 14).Value = Cells(i, 14).Value
        ElseIf j = 17 Then
        Cells(i, 14).Value = Cells(i, 14).Value & Cells(i, j).Value
        Else
        Cells(i, 14).Value = Cells(i, 14).Value & Cells(i, j).Value & ", "
        End If
    Next j
 Next i

 Columns("O:Q").Delete
 Columns("J:L").Delete

 End With
End Sub
```